# What is the equivalent of block level variable in mulesoft?

Tags: mule-studio, mulesoft

```
public static void method_one(){
    for(Integer i=0;i<10; i++){
        System.out.println('i');
    }
    //If we try to reference variable 'i', it will throw error.
}
```

I am trying to implement the above logic in mulesoft 4 and confused if we have equivalent of block level variable in mulesoft?

Can someone suggest.

Comment: In mule 4 flows/config or dataweave ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really comparable in Mule flows. In mule 4 flows `vars` are flow variables (same as `flowVars` in mule3). They are per event and are available to the flow they are defined and any flows/sub-flows they reference. They do not cross ‘transport barriers’ so they will not be available in another flow if they go across http,vm,jms or any other transport you use to connect your flows together.

Even within a `foreach` scope, if a variable is set, it is still available in the next iteration. However, each iteration of the foreach will overwrite the variable. And after the foreach only the last evaluated value is available outside of the foreach scope:

```
<foreach collection="#[[0,1,2,3]]">
    <set-variable variableName="i" value="#[(vars.i default 0) +1]" />
    <!-- logs 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 -->
    <logger level="INFO" message="Value of i: #[vars.i]" />
</foreach>

<!-- logs 4  -->
<logger level="INFO" message="Value of i: #[vars.i]" />
```

You can use `<remove-variable variableName="myVar" />`if you need to remove it for some reason.

If you're talking about Dataweave, then the `using` operator allows you to use a variable in scope:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var myarray=[0,1,2,3]
---
{
    bla: myarray map using (i=$$) { 
        index: i //works
    },
    outofscope: i //wont work
}
```